# r program, index a position by row number but column number is pulled from numeric values within column of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, select, indexing, position

So I have the following matrix:

| Occ1 | Occ2 | Occ3 | t |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | J | J | 2 |
| J | J | A | 3 |
| A | A | J | 1 |
| J | J | J | 2 |

The number in t corresponds with the column of the value that I want. See below:

| Occ1 | Occ2 | Occ3 | t |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | **J** | J | **2** |
| J | J | **A** | **3** |
| **A** | A | J | **1** |
| J | **J** | J | **2** |

In the end, I'm hoping for something like this:

J
A
A
J

I've tried a for loop and feel like I'm close. Clearly, the issue is setting t[1] only gives me the first value. However, I can't figure out how to make it run through every single value of t.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(matrix)){
   t <- t[1]
   position <- matrix[i,t]
   print(position)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach with `sapply` and indexing

```
unname(unlist(sapply(seq_along(data.frame(t(df))), function(x) 
  df[x,1:3][df$t[x]])))
[1] "J" "A" "A" "J"
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Occ1 = c("A", "J", "A", "J"), Occ2 = c("J", "J", 
"A", "J"), Occ3 = c("J", "A", "J", "J"), t = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: This works with my data! Thank you!